# Fixed inscreen div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple posts on my webpage. So it goes one post after post... Each post has an "info-bar" where you see the title, author, date, etc.. I want this bar to follow the scroll from the top of the post to the bottom of the post.

So I thought I could use jQuery and CSS. This is what I got so far but ain't working well :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $Margin = new Array;

$('.post').each(function(){
                var $Top = $(this).offset().top;
                var $Bot = $Top+$(this).height();

                $(this).attr('data-yTop', $Top);
                $(this).attr('data-yBot', $Bot);
                $(this).attr('data-MarginTop', $(this).css('margin-top'));

                //$Margin[$(this).attr('data-PostID')] = $(this).children('.p-image').html();
            });

            var $PageHeight = $(document).height();

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var $PageOffset = ($(window).scrollTop())+40;

                $('.p-info').each(function(){
                    var $Top = $(this).parent('.post').attr('data-yTop');
                    var $Bot = $(this).parent('.post').attr('data-yBot');

                    // On coupe un petit peu
                    var $InfoHeight = $(this).height();
                    var $Left = $(this).offset().left;

                    //$(this).parent().children('.p-image').html($Margin[$(this).parent('.post').attr('data-PostID')]+'<br />'+$PageOffset+'<br />Top:'+$Top+'<br />Bot:'+$Bot);

                    if($PageOffset >= $Top && $PageOffset <= ($Bot-$InfoHeight)-10){
                        $(this).css('position', 'fixed');
                        $(this).css('top', '60px');
                        $(this).css('left', $Left+'px');
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('position', '');
                        $(this).css('top', '');
                        $(this).css('left', '');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And this is the HTML :

```
                <div class="post" data-PostID="{{PostID}}" data-yTop="0" data-yBot="0" data-MarginTop="0">

                    <div class="p-image">
                        <!-- Post here (image/text) -->
                        <img src="{{URL}}" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="p-info">
                        <h2>{{Title}}</h2>
                        <p><a href="/{{PostedBy}}">{{PostedBy}}</a> {{Relative}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

I've been doing this for 3 days, I am tired and I need help. Can someone help me please ?

EDIT: Too get thing more complicated, I have a bar at the top, fix. So that 's why there's +40 in the code. Live at: http://en.dattroll.com/

So the problem on the page is that need to stick down the post

Comment: Why `$Margin = new Array;`? --> `$margin = [];`. Not sure about `if($PageOffset >= $Top && $PageOffset <= ($Bot-$InfoHeight)-10)` and `var $PageOffset = ($(window).scrollTop())+40;` mmm...Something is wrong.

Comment: Margin was a test, I was holding vars inside this but then I decied to switch to data-y* ... it's old code. I am not sure thought... This is working for going down, but then let's say I am at post 2 then post 1 goes back to the top and I want him to stick to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution... had to put my mind somewhere else... here it is :

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.post').each(function(){
                var $Top = $(this).offset().top;
                var $Bot = $Top+$(this).height();

                $(this).attr('data-yTop', $Top);
                $(this).attr('data-yBot', $Bot);
            });

            var $PageHeight = $(document).height();

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var $PageOffset = ($(window).scrollTop())+40;

                $('.p-info').each(function(){
                    var $Top = $(this).parent('.post').attr('data-yTop');
                    var $Bot = $(this).parent('.post').attr('data-yBot');

                    var $InfoHeight = $(this).height();
                    var $Left = $(this).offset().left;

                    if($PageOffset >= $Top && $PageOffset <= ($Bot-$InfoHeight)-10){
                        $(this).css('position', 'fixed');
                        $(this).css('top', '60px');
                        $(this).css('left', $Left+'px');
                    } else {
                        if($PageOffset >= $Top){
                            $(this).css('position', 'relative');
                            $(this).css('top', ($(this).parent('.post').height()-$InfoHeight)+'px');
                            $(this).css('left', '');
                            $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
                            $(this).css('padding-bottom', '0px');
                        } else {
                            $(this).css('position', '');
                            $(this).css('top', '');
                            $(this).css('left', '');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In css just use `position: fixed;`